# Documentation on bash completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete, shell-builtin

I've been unable to find complete documentation for the `complete` and `compgen` bash builtin commands. I'm on a Macintosh and `help complete` produces

`complete: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [-X filterpat] [-F function] [-C command] [name ...]`

with no documentation for the [-abcdefgjksuv] options.  The [gnu man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) is also silent about these options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't explicitly list those. They seem all to be short forms for various arguments to the `-A action` option:

> **-A *action***
>    The *action* may be one of the following to generate a list of possible completions:
>
> **alias** Alias names. May also be specified as `-a`.
>
> **builtin** Names of shell builtin commands. May also be specified as `-b`.

and so on.

Comment: D'oh!  I didn't read carefully.  Thx.